# Is it possible to return to a room in the state you left it, rather than being reset in GameMaker Studio 2?

Tags: game-maker, game-maker-studio-2

Currently I'm trying to implement a way that the user can quickly switch to a room that displays the instructions/controls. Once they're done reading them, they should be able to return to the room they were previously in in the state that they left it. What currently happens when I return to the room is that it has be reset to how it started.

I'm not calling anything like `room_restart()` or `game_restart()`, I'm just using `room_goto(num)` to navigate between the game room and the instructions room.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy way around would be to mark your room as persistent (`room_persistent = true`) before transitioning to instructions room and unmark it after transitioning back.

A more proper way would be to not transition the room at all, instead deactivating the game objects (`instance_deactivate_all(true)`) and then activating them again (`instance_activate_all()`) - just like you would for showing a pause menu.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this a lot in my games. All you need to do is save the current game state, then switch to a room with the controls. Use -  `game_save("example.dat")` then open it when you want to return. There are many tutorials on game saving and loading!

```
game_save("level.dat")
room_goto(rm_controls)
then
game_load("level.dat")
```

Hope that helps!